# In what order does IMAP return SEARCH results?

Tags: search, sorting, imap

I have been looking at the RFC spec for IMAP4 and I can't find out what order SEARCH is supposed to return matching messages. Is it even specified anywhere (newest to oldest or something?) or does it vary by implementation?

I'm guessing the latter is the case. If so, is there even any informal convention followed by most large servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, in my experience for simple searches, the results have always come increasing order (by message id or UID).

eg: UID SEARCH UNSEEN has returned values in increasing order when I've tried it.

However, you're right, the RFC does not appear to indicate that the ids must be returned in any order.